# I want to change the currency format like replace comma(,) with dots and dots with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the currency format like replace comma(,) with dots and dots with comma. like
22,22,22.00 to 22.22.22,00 currently i am using javascript package name jquery-formatcurrency.js it is doing good for US format but i want another region format like europen format.
I tried to change the package code but it is not working.

```
$('.formatCurrency').formatCurrency();
```

Comment: can't you change the `region`? it's supported

Comment: can you give ma a link with different regions example?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each string, and change the one you want, like that:

```js
var s = "22,22,22.00";
var next = "";
for (const c of s) {
   if(c == ".")
      next += ",";
   else if(c == ",")
      next += ".";
   else
      next += c;
}
console.log(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

To format numbers according to a specified locale use the `toLocaleString()` method

```js
const number = 222222.00;
const formatted = number.toLocaleString('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/,/g, '.');

console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intl` API to format the currency or any other numbers.

MDN Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Sample from MDN Page:

```js
const number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR"
  }).format(
    number,
  ),
);
// 123.456,79 €

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat("ja-JP", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "JPY"
  }).format(
    number,
  ),
);
// ￥123,457

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(
  new Intl.NumberFormat("en-IN", {
    maximumSignificantDigits: 3
  }).format(
    number,
  ),
);
// 1,23,000
```

Comment: can you plz provide ma a link to download this library.

Comment: You don't need to download this library, you can directly call this API. It's part of JavaScript! Make sure to read the docs properly! the link I gave in the answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regular expression..

```js
let 
  nStr_a = '22,22,22.00'
, nStr_b =  nStr_a.replace(/(\,|\.)/g, x=>({',':'.','.':','})[x])
  ;
console.log(nStr_b);
```